# How to update database for selective information from selected textboxes only? (asp.net c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm currently coding the SQL for a page to update user details.

How do I code in such a way that the program only updates the textboxes which the user keys information into (meaning to say that user can choose not to fill in all textboxes for update)?

I'm also not sure if I should be using DBnull. Please advise.

Below is my SQL code, and please click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJT55.jpg) to see my GUI

```
protected void btnconfirmupdatedetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string member = (String)Session["ssmem"];
    string strconnect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(strconnect);

    string strCommandText = "UPDATE Customer SET Password=@pass, Email=@email, Phone=@phone, Birthdate=@birthday, FirstName=@firstname, LastName=@lastname, Street1=@street1, Street2=@street2, City=@city, State=@state, Postal=@postal ";
    strCommandText+="WHERE Username=@member";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommandText, myConnect);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@member", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@phone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@birthday", SqlDbType.Date);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@street1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@street2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@state", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@postal", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);

    cmd.Parameters["@member"].Value = member;

    if (txtPassword.Text == "")
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@pass"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@pass"].Value = txtPassword.Text;
    }//=====

    if (txtEmail.Text == "")
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@email"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@email"].Value = txtEmail.Text;
    }//=====

    if (txtPhoneNumber.Text== "")
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@phone"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@phone"].Value = txtPhoneNumber.Text;
    }//=====

    if (txtFirstName.Text =="")
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@firstname"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@firstname"].Value = txtFirstName.Text;
    }//======

    if (txtBirthday.Text =="")
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@lastname"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@lastname"].Value = txtLastName.Text;
    }//======

    if (txtBirthday.Text =="")
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@birthday"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@birthday"].Value = txtBirthday.Text;
    }//======

    if (txtStreet1.Text =="")
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@street1"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@street1"].Value = txtStreet1.Text;
    }//=======

    if (txtStreet2.Text =="")
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@street2"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@street2"].Value = txtStreet2.Text;
    }//=======

    if (txtCity.Text =="")
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@city"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@city"].Value = txtCity.Text;
    }//========

    if (txtState.Text =="")
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@state"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@state"].Value = txtState.Text;
    }//========

    if (txtPostalCode.Text =="")
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@postal"].Value = DBNull.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@postal"].Value = txtPostalCode.Text;
    }

    myConnect.Open();

    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (result > 0)
    {
        lblErr.Text = "Update successful";
    }
    else
    {
        lblErr.Text = "Update fail";
    }

    myConnect.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simplest way is- You can load the current data in each textbox at the time of page_load.
Later when user wants to change any value, he will do the same and then update all text boxes values.

Comment: Sorry I'm still a bit confused, which part of my sql data should I load into page_load? @user3195546

Comment: Assume, if your user wants to update a his personal details who is currently logged in. Now your user will click on some button( maybe "Update MyProfile"). Now you are redirecting him to the form that you have shown in GUI link. On the page_load, load his current details on each textbox. he will view and modify those textboxes. And once he clicks on Update button, pass all these textboxes values in your query as a parameter.. Hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code snippet. I have used it in stored procedures before and know it works in stored procedures in MSSQL (you did not specify which DB).

```
UPDATE Customer SET Password=COALESCE(@pass, Password), Email= COALESCE(@email, Email)
```

Coalesce will return the first parameter with a non-null value. So if you pass null into one of the variables, the coalesce operator will select the value currently stored in the column (the second parameter of the coalesce method).

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) for more information about coalesce.

Comment: Hi, do I still need to use DBnull if I use coalesce? @mboldt

Comment: Yes, for empty fields you would pass DBnull.

Comment: Thank you so so much! It works! (By the way,i think the code you typed should be `Email =COALESCE(@email, Email)` )

Comment: Yep you are totally right, I edited the code. Glad it works. However consider the answer of user3195546 aswell, which might be more optimal regarding usability.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still confused as to which parts of the sql data i should place under page_load which he suggested

Comment: What he was trying to say is when you first load your page, you populate your form with the data from the database. So once the use lodas the form to update the data, the email field already contains the email from the database, etc. This way when you submit the form without editing a value, the previously stored value will just be set again and you don't have to worry about null values.

Comment: I see! But I intend to have many users in my website so there would be too much data to put  into page_load

Comment: In my opinion the edit form should only edit the data of 1 user. Maybe have an overview page listing the users (e.g. only the names) and when you click on the name the page redirects you to the edit form for that user. But that is a discussion about UI design and not about your question :)